# How can I extract URL and link text from HTML in Perl?

Tags: html, perl, parsing, url, cpan

I previously asked how to do this in Groovy.  However, now I'm rewriting my app in Perl because of all the CPAN libraries.

If the page contained these links:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>

<a href="http://www.apple.com">Apple</a>
```

The output would be:

```
Google, http://www.google.com
Apple, http://www.apple.com
```

What is the best way to do this in Perl?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Please look at using the [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) module for this.  It will fetch your web pages for you, and then give you easy-to-work with lists of URLs.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get( $some_url );
my @links = $mech->links();
for my $link ( @links ) {
    printf "%s, %s\n", $link->text, $link->url;
}
```

Pretty simple, and if you're looking to navigate to other URLs on that page, it's even simpler.

Mech is basically a browser in an object.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the print statement to include the link text, as requested by melling.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [HTML::LinkExtractor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::LinkExtractor) and [HTML::LinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::LinkExtor), part of the [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/) package.

HTML::LinkExtractor is similar to HTML::LinkExtor, except that besides getting the URL, you also get the link-text.

Comment: Unfortunately, HTML::LinkExtor can't give you the text inside the <a> tag, which he says he's interested in.  It only tells you the tag name and its attributes.

Comment: @cjm: I added a link to HTML::LinkExtractor which produces the link text in addition to the URLs.

Answer (score 6):

I like using [pQuery](http://search.cpan.org/dist/pQuery/lib/pQuery.pm) for things like this...

```
use pQuery;

pQuery( 'http://www.perlbuzz.com' )->find( 'a' )->each(
    sub {
        say $_->innerHTML . q{, } . $_->getAttribute( 'href' );
    }
);
```

Also checkout this previous stackoverflow.com question [Emulation of lex like functionality in Perl or Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160889/emulation-of-lex-like-functionality-in-perl-or-python#161977) for similar answers.

Answer (score 6):

If you're adventurous and want to try without modules, something like this should work (adapt it to your needs):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if($#ARGV < 0) {
  print "$0: Need URL argument.\n";
  exit 1;
}

my @content = split(/\n/,`wget -qO- $ARGV[0]`);
my @links = grep(/<a.*href=.*>/,@content);

foreach my $c (@links){
  $c =~ /<a.*href="([\s\S]+?)".*>/;
  $link = $1;
  $c =~ /<a.*href.*>([\s\S]+?)<\/a>/;
  $title = $1;
  print "$title, $link\n";
}
```

There's likely a few things I did wrong here, but it works in a handful of test cases I tried after writing it (it doesn't account for things like <img> tags, etc).

Comment: you are the master, you saved lot of time for me..thanks a ton.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this is to use XPath to query parsed HTML. It is needed in complex cases, like extract all links in div with specific class. Use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath for this.

```
  my $tree=HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($c);
  my $nodes=$tree->findnodes(q{//map[@name='map1']/area});
  while (my $node=$nodes->shift) {
    my $t=$node->attr('title');
  }
```

Comment: Also, add a $tree->delete to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 4):

[Sherm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254345/how-can-i-extract-urls-from-a-web-page-in-perl#254381) recommended [HTML::LinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::LinkExtor), which is almost what you want.  Unfortunately, it can't return the text inside the <a> tag.

[Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254345/how-can-i-extract-urls-from-a-web-page-in-perl#254687) recommended [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize).  That's probably the best solution.

If you find that WWW::Mechanize isn't to your liking, try [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tree/).  It will build a DOM-like tree out of the HTML, which you can then search for the links you want and extract any nearby content you want.

Answer (score 4):

Or consider enhancing HTML::LinkExtor to do what you want, and submitting the changes to the author.

Answer (score 4):

Previous answers were perfectly good and I know I’m late to the party but this got bumped in the [perl] feed so…

[XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML) is excellent for HTML parsing and unbeatable for speed. Set `recover` option when parsing badly formed HTML.

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_html(IO => \*DATA);
for my $anchor ( $doc->findnodes("//a[\@href]") )
{
    printf "%15s -> %s\n",
        $anchor->textContent,
        $anchor->getAttribute("href");
}

__DATA__
<html><head><title/></head><body>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.apple.com">Apple</a>
</body></html>
```

–yields–

```
     Google -> http://www.google.com
      Apple -> http://www.apple.com
```

Answer (score 3):

[HTML::LinkExtractor](http://search.cpan.org/~podmaster/HTML-LinkExtractor-0.13/LinkExtractor.pm) is better than HTML::LinkExtor

It can give both link text and URL.

Usage:

```
 use HTML::LinkExtractor;
 my $input = q{If <a href="http://apple.com/"> Apple </a>}; #HTML string
 my $LX = new HTML::LinkExtractor(undef,undef,1);
 $LX->parse(\$input);
 for my $Link( @{ $LX->links } ) {
        if( $$Link{_TEXT}=~ m/Apple/ ) {
            print "\n LinkText $$Link{_TEXT} URL $$Link{href}\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML is a structured markup language that has to be parsed to extract its meaning without errors. The module Sherm listed will parse the HTML and extract the links for you. Ad hoc regular expression-based solutions might be acceptable if you know that your inputs will always be formed the same way (don't forget attributes), but a parser is almost always the right answer for processing structured text.

Answer (score -1):

We can use regular expression to extract the link with its link text. This is also the one way.

```
local $/ = '';
my $a = <DATA>;

while( $a =~ m/<a[^>]*?href=\"([^>]*?)\"[^>]*?>\s*([\w\W]*?)\s*<\/a>/igs )
{   
    print "Link:$1 \t Text: $2\n";
}


__DATA__

<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>

<a href="http://www.apple.com">Apple</a>
```