# Why doesn't my Perl match operator match anything?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to Perl and playing around screen scraping and regex. I'm trying to extract the "title" name of the following HTML block:

```
... title="The Valley Downs Chicago"><img class="vimg120" ...
```

My simple Perl code to do so is:

```
@htmlBlocks = split ("margin-bottom:20px",$content);
foreach $item (@htmlBlocks)
{
if (/\stitle="([^"]*)"/six)
{
    print $1;
}
}
```

but it doesn't print anything.  while i'm troubleshooting it, i though i'd ask the experts if you see anything wrong or potentially problematic.  thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Is your html in `$_` variable?

Comment: thanks, Ivan, i just updated my code to show a bit more.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel -- refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254345/how-can-i-extract-urls-from-a-web-page-in-perl

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser.

Comment: He's reinventing the wheel because he's just learning the language and playing around with the concepts. That's how you learn.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default `//` search uses `$_` variable. If you want to search another variable then specify it before [`=~`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). Here is example:

```
@htmlBlocks = split ("margin-bottom:20px",$content);
foreach $item (@htmlBlocks) {
    if ($item =~ /\stitle="([^"]*)"/six) {
        print $1;
    }
}
```