# extracting text from HTML (Perl)

Tags: perl, http, tree, parsing, match

I'm doing a script that enters a page and extract and extract information from it.
The script I'm doing it in Perl.

Problem: Not how to start running the script because when I start it picks up the url like this and this is not what I want

`<a href="http://valeptr.com/scripts/runner.php?BA=6672&amp;hash=08c5c66839a468a11b7574e6ce02e0&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fdizzydollarsgpt.com%2Fmembers%2Fregister.php%3Fref%3Dthomasd24" target="_blank"><img alt="DizzyDollarsGPT" border="0" src="enter.php_files/runner.jpeg" /></a>`

And I want get this:

`<a href="http://valeptr.com/scripts/runner.php?PA=33425"
     target="_ptc" onclick="javascript:reloadpage(11)">
                        <img src="1appsearch.php_files/runner_007.gif"
    alt="Xray-cash" border="0">`

The all of code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#=======================================================================
#
# FILE: ValePTR.pl
#
# USAGE: ./ValePTR.pl user password
#
# DESCRIPTION:
#
# OPTIONS: ---
# REQUIREMENTS: libgetopt-declare-perl
# BUGS: ---
# NOTAS: ---
# AUTOR: Alejandro
# VERSION: 1.0
# CREATED: Lunes 5 de julio del 2010
# REVISION: 1
#=======================================================================

use warnings;
use strict;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Getopt::Long;
my($content, $search_result, @search_results);

    #Constructor del explorador con un UserAgent falso.
    my $Explorador = WWW::Mechanize->new( agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624' );
    $Explorador->get("file://home/alejandro/enter.php.html"); #Se procede a acceder a la dirección url para hacer el HTTP Post
    #$Explorador->field('username','miuser'); # Busca el campo username y pone el usuario
    #$Explorador->field('password','mipass'); # Busca el campo password y pone la contraseña
    #$Explorador->submit(); # Hace el HTTP POST

        #print $Explorador->content();
#parse $content with treebuilder
my $page = HTML::TreeBuilder->new();
$page->parse($Explorador->content());
$page->eof();


@search_results= $page->look_down(
sub{ $_[0]-> tag() eq 'a' and ($_[0]->attr('href'))}
);

foreach $search_result (@search_results){
my($url, $title, $summary);

$title = $page->look_down(
sub{ $_[0]-> tag() eq 'a' and ($_[0]->attr('href'))}
);
if($title)
{
print 'title: '.$title->as_HTML,"\n";
}
}


$page->delete;
```

The all of HTML code is here: http://gist.github.com/465568

PD:Please help me I've been here like 3 hours without success

Definitively what happens is that to take everything what there is one

`http://valeptr.com/scripts/runner.php?BA=`

and what I want to take is :

`http://valeptr.com/scripts/runner.php?PA=`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I extract URL and link text from HTML in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254345/how-can-i-extract-url-and-link-text-from-html-in-perl)

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `look_down()` can't distinguish between the links you want and the links you don't. Try a stronger filter like

```
@search_results = $page->look_down(
    sub {$_[0]->{tag} eq 'a'  &&
         $_[0]->attr('href') =~ /\?PA=/}); # only match http://...?PA=...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::TokeParser::Simple) for this just to avoid the overhead of building a document tree:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new('t.html');

while ( my $tag = $parser->get_tag('a') ) {
    my $href = $tag->get_attr('href');
    next unless $href =~ /runner\.php\?PA=[0-9]+\z/;

    print $tag->as_is;

    while ( my $token = $parser->get_token ) {
        print $token->as_is;
        last if $token->is_end_tag('/a');
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Output:

`<a href="http://valeptr.com/scripts/runner.php?PA=33425"
 target="_ptc" onclick="javascript:reloadpage(11)">
                    <img src="1appsearch.php_files/runner_007.gif"
alt="Xray-cash" border="0">
                </a> ... etc`