# How to get a matched substring from a string with regular expression in perl

Tags: html, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I extract URL and link text from HTML in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254345/how-can-i-extract-url-and-link-text-from-html-in-perl)

I am trying to get the substring in a string .There could be more than one matched string with that name in the string.

```
<LI>
<A
 HREF="65378161_12011_Q.pdf"> 
65378161_12011_Q.pdf

</A>
```

From the above string i want to get the file name "65378161_12011_Q.pdf".

```
if($line=~ m/((.*)Q\.pdf)/i ){
          my $inside=$2;
           print " file name:$inside \n";
     }
```

This is what i tried but it does not get the right sub string.
Can some one help on this.
I really appreciate if some one can answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

See the following script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "65378161_12011_Q.pdf";


if($string =~ m/((.*)?Q\.pdf)/i ){
    my $inside=$2;
    print " file name:$inside \n";
}
```

Your code just lack the '?' character to tell the regex to be not greedy.

Another way is to match all of the characters that is not a 'Q' before itself :

```
m/(^[^Q]+)?Q\.pdf/i
```

**Edit**:
Because you had edited your post with a different spec :
If you need to parse HTML, I recommend to use a proper module :

> Don't parse or modify html with regular expressions! See one of
>   HTML::Parser's subclasses: HTML::TokeParser, HTML::TokeParser::Simple,
>   HTML::TreeBuilder(::Xpath)?, HTML::TableExtract etc. If your response
>   begins "that's overkill. i only want to..." you are wrong.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy and
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for why not to use regex on HTML

(This is a reminder about using regex to parse HTML from #perl channel on irc.freenode.org)

**Edit 2:**

Here a complete working example :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content('
<LI>
<A
 HREF="65378161_12011_Q.pdf"> 
65378161_12011_Q.pdf

</A>
');

$tree->look_down("_tag", "a")->as_text =~ m/(^[^Q]+)Q\.pdf/i && print "$1\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ..I changes the question and i tried your recommendation but did not work ..

Comment: input string: <LI><A HREF="65378161_12011_Q.pdf"> 65378161_12011_Q.pdf</A>--input 

regular expression -- m/(^[^Q]+)?Q\.pdf/i





output

 file name:<LI><A HREF="65378161_12011_

Comment: Some how this also did not work the out put what i got after the regular expression matching is file name:<LI><A HREF="65378161_12011_

Comment: I wish you'd delete the regex solution, or at least put it at the bottom of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Use a HTML parser.](http://htmlparsing.com/)

```
use strictures;
use Web::Query qw();
my $w = Web::Query->new_from_html(<<'HTML');
<LI>
<A
HREF="65378161_12011_Q.pdf">
65378161_12011_Q.pdf

</A>
HTML

$w->find('a')->attr('href');
# expression returns '65378161_12011_Q.pdf'
$w->find('a')->text;
# expression returns ' 65378161_12011_Q.pdf '
```

Comment: That's a nifty looking module I haven't used yet :)

Answer (score -1):

Since . will match everything, simply remove the parenthesis around it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $line = "65378161_12011_Q.pdf";

if ($line =~ m/(.*Q\.pdf)/i )
{
  my $inside = $1;
  print "filename = $inside\n";
}
```

Produces the correct output.

Hope it helps.

Manny

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion this also did not work but again i changed the question can you see please check my question one more time as the input string is different now