# Parsers and Compilers for Dummies. Where to start?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

This is a good [listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785/learning-resources-on-parsers-interpreters-and-compilers), but what is the best one for a complete newb in this area. One for someone coming from a higher level background (VB6,C#,Java,Python) - not to familiar with C or C++. I'm much more interested in hand-written parsing versus Lex/Yacc at this stage.

If I had just majored in Computer Science instead of Psychology I might have taken a class on this in college. Oh well.

Comment: BTW, hand-writing parsers instead of using YACC/similar does have its place, but it seems the lexing/scanning stage is very seldom handwritten. Also, most mature programming languages seem to have an analog to both Lex and Yacc.

Comment: Does CPython? I was looking at that source code and it seemed to be hand-written. PHP seemed to be Yacc'd, I think. I think the Python one is going to be the easiest for me to grok. I'm not sure I follow any of the generated C code yet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please have a look at: [learning to write a compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler)

Also interesting:

- [how to write a programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229854/how-to-write-a-programming-language)
- [parsing where can i learn about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081/parsing-where-can-i-learn-about-it)
- [learning resources on parsers interpreters and compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785/learning-resources-on-parsers-interpreters-and-compilers) (ok you already mentioned this one.

And there are more on the topic. But I can give a short introduction:

The first step is the lexical analysis. A stream of characters is translated into a stream of tokens. Tokens can be simple like == <= + - (etc) and they can be complex like identifiers and numbers. If you like I can elaborate on this.

The next step is to translate the tokenstream into a syntaxtree or an other representation. This is called the parsing step.

Before you can create a parser, you need to write the grammar. For example we create an expression parser:

**Tokens**

```
addOp = '+' | '-';
mulOp = '*' | '/';
parLeft = '(';
parRight = ')';
number = digit, {digit};
digit = '0'..'9';

Each token can have different representations: + and = are both addOp and 
23 6643 and 223322 are all numbers.
```

**The language**

```
exp = term | exp, addOp, term;  
// an expression is a series of terms separated by addOps.
term = factor | term, mulOp, factor;
// a term is a series of factors separated by mulOps
factor = addOp, factor | parLeft, exp, parRight | number;
// a factor can be an addOp followed by another factor, 
// an expression enclosed in parentheses or a number.
```

**The lexer**

We create a state engine that walks through the char stream, creating a token

```
s00 
  '+', '-' -> s01       // if a + or - is found, read it and go to state s01.
  '*', '/' -> s02
  '('      -> s03
  ')'      -> s04
  '0'..'9' -> s05
  whitespace -> ignore and retry  // if a whitespace is found ignore it
  else ERROR      // sorry but we don't recognize this character in this state.
s01
  found TOKEN addOp     // ok we have found an addOp, stop reading and return token
s02 
  found TOKEN mulOp
s03
  found TOKEN parLeft
s04
  found TOKEN parRight
s05
  '0'..'9'     -> s05    // as long as we find digits, keep collecting them
  else found number      // last digit read, we have a number
```

**Parser**

It is now time to create a simple parser/evaluator. This is complete in code. Normally they are created using tables. But we keep it simple. Read the tokens and calculate the result.

```
ParseExp
  temp = ParseTerm // start by reading a term
  while token = addOp do
    // as long as we read an addop keep reading terms
    if token('+') then temp = temp + ParseTerm  // + so we add the term
    if token('-') then temp = temp - ParseTerm  // - so we subtract the term
  od
  return temp // we are done with the expression

ParseTerm
  temp = ParseFactor
  while token = mulOp do
    if token('*') then temp = temp * ParseFactor
    if token('/') then temp = temp / ParseFactor
  od
  return temp

ParseFactor
  if token = addOp then
    if token('-') then return - ParseFactor  // yes we can have a lot of these
    if token('+') then return ParseFactor
  else if token = parLeft then
    return ParseExpression
    if not token = parRight then ERROR
  else if token = number then
    return EvaluateNumber   // use magic to translate a string into a number
```

This was a simple example. In real examples you will see that error handling is a big part of the parser.

I hope this clarified a bit ;-).

Comment: Thanks. This is great stuff. I guess a few of the stages were confusing me. Now I can go read up more on each stage.

Comment: great answer !!

Answer (score 2):

If you're  a complete n00b, the most accessible resource (in both senses of the term) is probably [Jack Crenshaw's tutorial](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/).  It's nowhere near comprehensive but for getting started, I can't think of anything close except for books that are long out of print.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest an article that I wrote called [Implementing Programming Languages using C# 4.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/programminglanguagetoools.aspx). I've tried to make it accessible for newcomers. It isn't comprehensive, but afterwards it should be easier to understand other more advanced texts.