# How to understand everything regarding a Simple Program creation?

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I have referred quite a few books on C, C++, etc. in fact i have even read the Dragon book on Compilers.
But my basic doubt remains, 
is there any link or book i can read which explains a simple C program creating from writing source code in a Editor to Compilation to Linking?

Would appreciate an internet link is provided.

Comment: Can this earlier thread help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426239/parsers-and-compilers-for-dummies-where-to-start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As example this is for *nix OS: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/how-to-write-compile-and-execute-c-program-on-unix-os-with-hello-world-example/. (there are source code edited by text editor, not by IDE)
I found this link using google with "C hello world howto" request. You can try similar requests If you need Windows (or other OS) specific manual

Answer (score 0):

Well... good introductory books are

- [C++ Without Fear](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246950)
- [C Programming: A Modern Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393979504)
- And Bruce Eckel's free [Thinking in C++](http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html)

These cover very well compiling and linking in their first chapters, as well as execution and requirements. These are the books which did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Guess, it depends- if you are looking for the basics, whatever you grab will get you in Line.

But if you have a burring desire to know what is happening under the hood- drinking from the closer source is a recommendation - in which case : http://www.duntemann.com/assembly.htm is a wise choice. Ya... read and re-read The Book if you have to till it makes sense. The Book itself will guide you all the way out.

Good Luck,